# How to resubscribe a subscriber which is already unsubscribed from All Subscribers List

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I have used this code to get a subscriber from particular list but I am trying to get from all subscribers list.  It's not working for that.

```
%%[

var @ll_sub,@emailaddr,@process_subkey,@subscription,@subscription,@errorCode,@ll_statusCode

SET @ll_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, "EmailAddress", @emailaddr)
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, "SubscriberKey", "email123")


set @subscription = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
//process_listid from your original email
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "ID",27122)
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "IDSpecified", "true" )
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "Status", "Active" )
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "StatusSpecified", "true" )
AddObjectArrayItem( @ll_sub, "Lists", @subscription )

SET @ll_statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@ll_sub, @subscription, @errorCode)

IF @ll_statusCode != "OK" THEN
    RaiseError(@ll_statusMsg, 0, @ll_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF
 ]%%
```

It's fine with either AMPScript or SSJS.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will update the status of a list subscriber

```
<script  runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1");
var myList = List.Init("List External Key");
var status = myList.Subscribers.Retrieve({Property:"Status",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"Unsubscribed"});

for (var i = 0; i < status.length; i++) 
{
    var tt = status[i].SubscriberKey;
    var results = myList.Subscribers.Tracking.Retrieve({Property:"SubscriberKey", SimpleOperator:"equals", Value:tt});
    results.Status = "Active";
    var subObj = Subscriber.Init(tt);
    var status1 = subObj.Update(results);
    var bb = Stringify(status1); 
    Write(bb);
}
</script>
```